# Implement styles from a span tag now that it's contents are in an array

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, reactjs, react-props

I'm trying to bring back the styling on all these array elements that were previously in span tags with their own classes but I don't know how to go about it. 
Still relatively a newbie so I'd appreciate newbie-level explanations. Thanks.

This is the App.js for everything:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import './calc.css';
import Result from './result_component';
import Key from './key_component';


let Key_Data = ['AC', '+/-', '%', '÷', '7', '8', '9', '*', '4', '5', '6', '-', '1', '2', '3', '+', '0', '.', '=']

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div class="container">
        <Result/>

        <div class="keys">

        {
            Key_Data.map((key) => {
              return <Key name={key} />
            })
        }   

        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the key_component.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './calc.css';

function Key(props){
    return(
        <div className="key operator zero-key">
            {props.name}
        </div>
    )
}



export default Key;
```

This is the original CSS stylesheet containing all styling

```
.container{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 0 1 60%;
    width:700px;
}

.keys,.result{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 0 1 100%;
}

.result{
    height: 60px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    background: grey;
    color:white;
    padding:0 10px;
    font-size:50px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

.key{
    display:flex;
    flex: 0 1 25%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-top:none;
    border-left:none;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

.operator{
    background-color: darkorange;
    color: white;
    border-right: none;
}

.zero-key{
    flex-grow: 2;
}
```

This is the original HTML with the span tags

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="result">0</div>
    <div class="keys">
        <span class="key reset-key">AC</span>
        <span class="key negative sign">+/-</span>
        <span class="key sign">%</span>
        <span class="key operator">/</span>
        <span class="key number">7</span>
        <span class="key number">8</span>
        <span class="key number">9</span>
        <span class="key operator">*</span>
        <span class="key number">4</span>
        <span class="key number">5</span>
        <span class="key number">6</span>
        <span class="key operator">-</span>
        <span class="key number">1</span>
        <span class="key number">2</span>
        <span class="key number">3</span>
        <span class="key operator">+</span>
        <span class="key number zero-key">0</span>
        <span class="key number dot">.</span>
        <span class="key  operator">=</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since your css doesn't reference the tag name, but only the class name (for example `.key` ), it should continue to be applied, even when the element has changed to a div.  Are you saying the elements are no longer styled once you transform each one into a `div`?

Comment: I'm no longer using the HTML file here. I just posted it to give further clarification on the question. So it's just the 1st 3 documents that are active

Comment: Is the css file getting pulled in to the build at all?

Comment: yes the css file is imported into both the app.js and key_component files

Comment: I don't see any reason for a problem.  The styles in that sheet should apply to the html in your App as you've shown it here.

Comment: exactly, i don't get it either. as you can see from the code, some of the styles are showing on the app because I called their classes in the div in key_component.js. But the thing is now those styles are applied to everything in that div. However, each element in the array originally had specific classes per their span attributes as can be seen in the HTML file. So i just want to be able to specify those classes for each array element so that they can each have their individual styles

Answer (score 0):

In order to provide classes for an element based on one of its props, you can combine a map with lodash.findKey and the classnames module. This should get you started:

```js
import classnames from 'classnames';
import { findKey } from 'lodash';

function Key(props){

    const map = {
      'zero-key': [0,"0"],
      'operator': ['*','-','+'],
      'number': [1,2,3],
    }

    const classes = classnames(
       'key',
       'operator',
       findKey( map, o => {
          return o.indexOf( props.name ) > -1
       },
    );

    return(
        <div className={ classes }>
            {props.name}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the response. I tried it as you said but there has been no change. It' still the same as it was. The styling for the operator class has been applied to everything and the CSS of the other classes have been ignored

Comment: Are the other css classes getting applied?

Comment: I fixed a typo in the code above, you could try it again. But also, you need to know if the props.name are strings or integers. In other words, are they `1` or `"1"`. The code above is expected them to be integers.

Comment: the elements in the array are strings. I used your code as is and then changed all the integers to strings but the result is still the same